# How to get the line number of nth match?

Tags: bash, awk, grep, numbers, line

Let's say I have the following file:

```
* cat
* dog
* cat
* fish
* fish
* cat
* turtle
```

Let's say I want to find the line number of the second match for cat, how can I do that?

Comment: Sorry, this is not the way StackOverflow works. Questions of the form "I want to do X, please give me tips and/or sample code" are considered off-topic. Please visit the [help] and read [ask], and especially read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: This might help you forward. The following will print the second match of `cat`: `awk '/cat/&&(++c==2)'`

Comment: You got the answer to the question you asked but if this is related to the input shown in your previous question, this is not the right way to do what you really want. Post a new question with more truly representative sample input/output if you'd like help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$ awk '/cat/{c++} c==2{print NR;exit}' file
3
```

count the cats, print the line number and exit after the required match value.

Comment: slightly more efficient since it only tests `c` on the `cat` lines: `awk '/cat/ && (++c==2){print NR;exit}' file`

Comment: search for how to pass variables to `awk`.

Comment: Since it's not quite as simple as just passing the value of the shell variable into awk as an awk variable, change `awk '/${element}/{` to `awk -v elt="$element" '$0 ~ elt{...`. Just remember **awk is not shell**.

Answer (score 1):

The awk solutions are more I/O efficient but I wanted to point out there is a pure shell solution also:

```
grep -n cat | head -2 | tail -n 1 | cut -d: -f1
```

Feel free to substitute any other regular expression for cat.